# External JavaScript file will load, but not execute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to put a script I had tested succesfully inline in an external file. The script worked fine when I had it inside a pair of html script-tags on the page itself, but when I try to call the script externally the function inside it does not execute and the console does not log the various console.log stages in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("Script loaded!");

  $("#btn-april-en").click(function() {


    console.log("Confirm click!");


    $.getJSON("books.json", function(data, status) {

      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);

      $("#img-container").html("<img src=" + data.aprilWitchEn.coverIMG + ">");
      $("#title-en").html("h3>Title: ") + data.aprilWitchEn.title + "</h3>"
    });

  });

});

   
<head>
  <title>Title here</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  <!-- jQuery, Bootstrap etc-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- My CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css">
  <!-- My JavaScript -->

  <!-- Scripts do not load correctly right now -->

  <script type="javascript" src="../assets/js/bookLoader.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have tried to debug it myself with the python http.server, which indicates bootLoader.js is found and loaded:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:20] "GET /assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:20] "GET /assets/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:20] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:20] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:26] "GET /en/start.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:32] "GET /en/books.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [29/May/2020 08:22:32] "GET /assets/js/bookLoader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But when I press the button with the correct ID, nothing happens.
If there is any more relevant information I can provide to make finding the cause of this problem easier, please let me know?

(A note on directory structure: the HTML above is stored in /root/en/books.html and the JS is in /root/assets/js/bookLoader.js, so the src jumps up a directory level to find the file.)

Comment: The JavaScript at the top of your snippet is supposed to be `bookLoader.js`? Do you not see anything in the browser console?

Comment: That is correct, the JS snippet is bookLoader.JS. There is nothing in the Chrome console, either on load or on pressing the button. Interestingly, if I screw up the src to bookLoader.js, the console logs a 404 error, but when the src path is correct it does not log anything in the browser console.

Comment: (Sidenote: @Chase As a test, I pasted the entire contents of bookLoader.js into the browser-console on the page and then it console logged "Script loaded" and "Confirm click!" as intended, but when it's called from the external script nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your scripts at the end of your html file, before the closing body tag.

```
<body>

  <!-- Your HTML here -->

  <script type="javascript" src="../assets/js/bookLoader.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```